# Is it possible to download and run IPhone apps on an IPhone emulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, app-store, emulation

I am tasked to provide an IPhone client app for our SaaS website. I have never written an IPhone application, nor do I have an IPhone at the moment. Before I can decide whether or not I want to do this myself or outsource this, I'd like to try a few apps myself to get a feeling for the UI.

Is there any IPhone emulator I might use to download and run apps from the App Store? I do have an Intel-based Mac if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The first major hurdle is that the apps from the app store are compiled for the ARM processor, and your Mac is x86.

The only thing you can do is compile projects from source. Luckily, Apple has many [sample projects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) which demonstrate various features, [including the UI widgets](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html).

Comment: Additionally, there are several open source iPhone applications you can try out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around